# Espresso: Scrolling on recyclerview with no unique id or text

Tags: android, android-espresso

I am facing an issue with scrolling inside a `RecyclerView` in my android Espresso tests. I think I have read lot about different solutions and the closest I came was with a `ViewHolderMatcher`. Below is the `ViewHolderMatcher` I wrote,

```
    public static Matcher<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> withHolderTimeView(final String text) {
    return new BoundedMatcher<RecyclerView.ViewHolder, AccountViewHolder>(AccountViewHolder.class) {

        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {
            description.appendText("No ViewHolder found with text: " + text);
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean matchesSafely(AccountViewHolder item) {
           TextView accountNum = (TextView) item.itemView.findViewById(R.id.account_number_value);
            if (accountNum == null) {
                return false;
            }
            return accountNum.getText().toString().contains(text);
        }
    };
}
```

The issue here is that the `R.id.account_number_value` and the corresponding text that I pass to match can appear multiple times. There is no unique id with a unique value.

The only way I can get a unique item is by combining with a sibling view and the text of the view I am looking for. Is there any way I can add a sibling relation in above `ViewHolderMatcher`?

Or is there any better way to scroll in this situation?

Comment: Just wanted to update that I have figured out an interim solution by checking for multiple items using && and then return that boolean result from the matcher. This works fine for me. But the problem is that if one of my check (while combining items) fails, I cant pin  point which one is failing in the logs.